# Why is the graph of a rational map independent of the choice of representative?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $\phi:X\rightarrow Y$ is a rational map of varieties, why is the graph of $\phi$ well-defined? That is, if $\langle \rho,U\rangle$ and $\langle \psi,V\rangle$ are two representatives of $\phi$ (so that $U,V\subseteq X$ open, and $\rho\vert_{U\cap V}=\psi\vert_{U\cap V}$), why is the closure of the image of $\rho$ equal to the closure of the image of $\psi$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $U\cap V$ is Zariski dense in both $U$ and $V$ (by irreducibility of $X$), and so both graphs
are obtained by closing up the graph of $\rho_{| U\cap V}$ (which of course coincides with the graph of $\phi_{| U \cap V}$).

Comment: Ah, I was forgetting that the image of a dense set is dense in the image.

Comment: May I ask how to prove both graphs are obtained by closing up the graph of $\phi_{|U\cap V}$? I think the topology on $X\times Y$ is not the product topology, and we only know some dense property on $X$.