# Why is the graph of a rational function well-defined?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be irreducible quasi-projective varieties, and $\varphi:X\to Y$ be a rational map. Why is the graph of $\varphi$ well-defined? More specifically, if $U$ and $V$ are open subsets of $X$ where $\varphi$ is regular, why are the closures of $\{(x,\varphi(x))\mid x\in U\}$ and $\{(x,\varphi(x))\mid x\in V\}$ in $X\times Y$ the same?

I found this old post [Why is the graph of a rational map independent of the choice of representative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5955/why-is-the-graph-of-a-rational-map-independent-of-the-choice-of-representative) and I am asking the same question because I don't know how to proceed from there. I understand $U$ and $V$ are dense, but how do we use this when working with the graph?

What I tried: $\Gamma_{\varphi|_U}=\Gamma_{\varphi|_{U\cap V}}\cup\Gamma_{\varphi|_{U\backslash V}}$ and taking closures doesn't seem to lead anywhere. I tried to look at the map $\psi:X\to X\times Y,x\mapsto(x,\varphi(x))$, but I don't know what we can say about its image (its image as a regular map on an open subset) that would be helpful. I also tried to think about a bihomogeneous polynomial $f$ that vanishes on $\Gamma_{\varphi|_U}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a natural isomorphism
$$
U \to \Gamma_{\varphi\vert_U},
\qquad 
x \mapsto (x,\varphi(x))
$$
that takes $U \cap V$ to $\Gamma_{\varphi\vert_{U \cap V}}$. Since $U  \cap V$ is dense in $U$, we have
$$
\Gamma_{\varphi\vert_U} = 
\overline{\Gamma_{\varphi\vert_{U \cap V}}}
$$
(the closure is taken in $U \times Y$). Similarly,
$$
\Gamma_{\varphi\vert_V} = 
\overline{\Gamma_{\varphi\vert_{U \cap V}}}
$$
(now the closure is taken in $V \times Y$). Finally,
$$
\overline{\Gamma_{\varphi\vert_U}} =
\overline{\Gamma_{\varphi\vert_{U \cap V}}} =
\overline{\Gamma_{\varphi\vert_V}}
$$
(now the closures are taken in $X \times Y$).